# jQuery syntax for variable attributes

Tags: jquery, syntax, var

I'm trying to compact and optimize some code and have the following types that I would like to compact, but can't get the correct syntax for that:

```
var my_field_name = $('#my_field_name'); // a multiple select
var my_array = {"0":"123","1","456","2":"789"};
my_array = $.parseJSON(my_array);
$.each(my_array, function (k, v) {
    $("#my_field_name option[value="+v+"]").prop("selected", true);
}
```

so far everything's working fine, but I "would like" to use `my_field_name` in the `$.each` loop like `my_field_name.("option[value="+v+"]").prop("selected", true);` but this seems to be an incorrect syntax.
Is the `$("#my_field_name option[value="+v+"]")` the only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `my_field_name` is a jQuery instance for the `select` element, you'd use `children` to access its `options` elements:

```
$.each(my_array, function (k, v) {
    my_field_name.children('option[value=' + v + ']').prop("selected", true);
}
```

...but see also below.

It's probably worth noting that your `my_array` variable doesn't point to an array. In fact, that line is a syntax error (because you've used a comma after `"1"` rather than a colon). (If you'd used the colon you'd have an object with the keys `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`, but it wouldn't be an *array*. Granted, standard "arrays" in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), but...) I think you wanted:

```
var my_array = ["123", "456", "789"];
```

You also don't use `$.parseJSON` on something that isn't a string.

**If** `my_array` actually ends up being an *array* (either because you've written it literally or because it's parsed from a JSON string like `["123", "456", "789"]`), rather than using `children` you may be better off just looping through the options:

```
// Let's assume you get jsonString from somewhere else, and it's really a string,
// as though you had this code: jsonString = '["123", "456", "789"]'
var my_array = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
$.each($("#my_field_name")[0].options, function(index, option) {
    if ($.inArray(option.value, my_array) !== -1) {
        option.selected = true;
    }
});
```

The `options` property on a raw `select` DOM element (note the `[0]` to get to the raw element) is an array-like object with a `length` property, so `$.each` will loop over it using indexes. `$.inArray` will then see if the `option`'s `value` is present in the array. You don't need to cache the lookup using the `my_field_name` variable because you only do the lookup once.

But note that that *won't* work if the JSON string is `{"0": "123", "1": "456", "2": "789"}`, because `$.inArray` won't work with a non-array object like that.

---

Re your comment below:

> ... in your example you're still using $("#my_field_name") and that is what I was trying to avoid, since $("#my_field_name") is already cached on top of the script and though I thought of using the var name instead of repeating $("#my_field_name") every time I need to reference that field.

If you're *already* doing

```
var my_field_name = $("#my_field_name");
```

...above it in the code, then *naturally* in any of the examples in this answer, if you see `$("#my_field_name")`, you can replace it directly with `my_field_name`. So for instance, if you see:

```
$.each($("#my_field_name")[0].options, function(index, option) {
```

and you already have `my_field_name` in a variable, you can change it to this;

```
$.each(my_field_name[0].options, function(index, option) {
```

Comment: Yes, the quotes were just a mistype here and the array (forgot to post it here, is parsed by $.parseJSON). But that ends up being the same thing (as I may figure out). I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Mario: I figured. Doesn't change the answer. :-) Happy coding,

Comment: So in your opinion, using the cached variable my_field_name is a better option than using the full $("#my_field_name")?

Comment: @Mario: Actually, with apologies, I completely misread the question. :-) I've read it correctly now, and updated the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Tanks T.J. but although it seems like another solution, in your example you're still using $("#my_field_name") and that is what I was trying to avoid, since $("#my_field_name") is already cached on top of the script and though I thought of using the var name instead of repeating $("#my_field_name") every time I need to reference that field.

Comment: @Mario: See the note I added to the end.

Comment: Thanks. Missed it. That's really the kind of syntax I was trying to implement and make use of the cached reference. Thanks!